# drag and drop with JSF - richfaces4.0

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I have recently started working on JSF and am using richfaces 4.0. I am looking for a working example to implement drag and drop functionality in Tree. I have tree working however I am not able to figure out how to get drang and drop working in the tree. What I am looking for is

```
Node1
Node2
Node3
Node4
```

So I should be able to place, say, "Node1" in between "Node3" and "Node4" and all other Nodes above "Node3" should move 1 index up.

Will appriciate any help on this :)

Thanks,
Kulpreet

Comment: The RichFaces [Drag and Drop Demo](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dragDrop&skin=blueSky) is a good start point for your case. Have you tried to apply it in your Tree? Are you having any specific issue?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, the demo, apart from abandoned years ago, is so broken. The dragDropEventBean.processDrop dropListener method referenced in the .xhtml source doesn't exist in the DragDropBean example source. And that's exactly where I'm getting exceptions about the "property" (it should be a method, but oh well) not being found in the bean (which is false).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working, there are minor issues in the code however, the basic functionality works.

```
                                    <rich:dragSource type="#{element.type}" 
                                                     dragValue="#{element}"
                                                     dragIndicator="actInd"
                                                     >

                                    </rich:dragSource>
                                    <rich:dropTarget acceptedTypes="#{element.type}" dropValue="#{element}"
                                                     dropListener="#{modelTree.activityDropListener}"
                                                     render="tabs"
                                                     >

                                    </rich:dropTarget>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{element}"/>   
                                </a4j:outputPanel>
```

- activityDropListener have code to pick up the value of the dragged node and the drop position and update the List which constucts the treeon UI

Thanks,
Kulpreet